# Deep Learning in a Camera

Tags: deep-learning

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this.
Is it possible to run deep learning inside a camera and if so, how?
I want to be able to take a picture and then use deep learning techniques to do image recognition by using it against hundreds or thousands or millions of other images. Is the only way to do this by taking a picture, sending it to a cloud or something like that and then input it in some model?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do image/object detection in real time using your camera and specialized libraries like Yolo.

See: https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

However, you will want to train your recognition model before, using objects/images' labelling. This is the most adapted library if you have to deal with millions of pictures. It requires a good PC and GPU, or a GPU cloud service, to learn fast enough.

On the other hand, if you are limited in your hardware, it is always possible to use tiny-yolo and low hardware setup like rasperry-py.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. I think my problem might be with training using objects/images' labeling. How can I label potentially millions of facebook pictures? Would it be by the user's profile name or is there a way to find out the name of the person by some scraping method?

Comment: Yolo is not very good to recognize specific faces, it is better for general recognition. For person recognition, OpenCV is faster than Yolo. For instance: https://elbruno.com/2019/05/22/vscode-lets-do-some-facerecognition-with-20-lines-in-python/
If your question is more specific, it's better to ask a new question instead of a comment.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks Nicholas. It seems they are using a webcam. How would one use one's personal camera from say, a regular camera or a phone?

Comment: You should use smaller libraries like tiny yolo or tf lite for smartphones. For individual camera, the stream should be process in a device like a pc